# What is the point of @JoinColumn in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know that `@JoinColumn` is used for creating the foreign key column, but my question is little bit another.
I noticed that if I have main entity with `mapped by` and dependent entity with no `@JoinColumn`, than the hibernate creates two tables correctly anyway.

For example, I have Passport ans Person:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity

public class Person {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private int age;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person") 
    Passport passport;
}
```

Passport entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity

public class Passport {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    private int series;
    @NonNull
    private int number;

    @OneToOne
//    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id") //with or without this line the hibernate creates person_id in the Passport table
    @ToString.Exclude
    Person person;

}
```

In the both ways (with or without @JoinColumn annotation) hibernte creates the following tables:

Person table:

```
###################
id ## name ## age #
###################
```

Passport table:

```
#####################################
id ## series ## number ## person_id #
#####################################
```

So what's the point of @JoinColumn annotation if there's no difference?

Comment: It gives you control of how you manage foreign key in your relational tables, and also a good practice to follow. Like the @Column( name = "my_column" ), where you have control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@JoinColumn](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) indicates that this entity is the owner of the relationship, that the corresponding table has a column with a foreign key to the referenced table.

`@JoinColumn` annotation is not mandatory. If you will not specify it framework will perform default configuration instead. Hibernate and JPA follows [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration). This means that the developer only needs to specify not standard aspects some custom definitions.

In case of `@JoinColumn`, the default column name will be generated like: `[field_name]_[id_column_name]`.

In your case:

`[field_name]` - is `person` field of `Passport` entity.

`[id_column_name]` - is `@Id` column of related entity. It is `id` field of `Person` entity.

According to [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/):

> 2.2.5. Mapping entity associations/relationships
>
> If no @JoinColumn is declared on the owner side, the defaults apply. A
> join column(s) will be created in the owner table and its name will be
> the concatenation of the name of the relationship in the owner side, _
> (underscore), and the name of the primary key column(s) in the owned
> side.

So if you need to override the default convention then that's exactly what `@JoinColumn` is for.

It covering:

- specify the name of the foreign key column
- specify the name of the column referenced by this foreign key column
- specify column definition
- specify or control the generation of a foreign key definition
- specify the name of the table that contains the column
- whether the property is a unique key
- whether the column is included in SQL UPDATE statements generated by the persistence provider